# Same directory structure for the out directory in Typescript, how?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

The **problem**: the structure of `dist` Typescript output directory changes based on the imported modules in my `server/app.ts`.

Directory `server` holds server (Node) files, `shared` holds common models (classes) while `dist` is the out directory:

```
├───dist
├───server
│       app.ts
│       tsconfig.json
│
├───shared
│       customer.model.ts
|       index.ts
│
│── package.json
│── tsconfig.json
```

If I run `tsc -p server` with the following `server/app.ts`:

```
import * as path from 'path';

// ..
console.log('Starting the server...');
```

Here is the **output** `dist` folder:

```
└───server
        app.js
        app.js.map
```

As soon as I import `shared/customer.model.ts`:

```
import * as path from 'path';
import { Customer } from '../shared';

// ..
console.log('Starting the server...');
```

It becomes:

```
└───server
    ├───server
    │       app.js
    │       app.js.map
    │
    └───shared
            customer.model.js
            customer.model.js.map
            index.js
            index.js.map
```

File `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist/server",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

I'd like to have a **predictable directory structure** like the following, I know I should play with `rootDir` and `rootDirs` options, but I don't know how:

```
├───server
│       app.js
│       app.js.map
│
└───shared
        customer.model.js
        customer.model.js.map
        index.js
        index.js.map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of this [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-does---outdir-moves-output-after-adding-a-new-file), this should produce the desired structure:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": <path-to-the-parent of server, shared and dist>
    "outDir": "../dist",
```

Comment: Nope, you get the error: `customer.model.ts` is out of the rootDir :(

Comment: It should not happen if `shared` is in `rootDir`, and `customer.model.ts` is in `shared`. Either it's a`customer.mode.ts` from a different directory (is it symlinked to another place? then `--preserveSymlinks: true` might help (or make things worse)), or something else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get folder structure in `dist/` like this

```
├───server
│       app.js
│       app.js.map
│
└───shared
    customer.model.js
    customer.model.js.map
    index.js
    index.js.map
```

I think that your base `tsconfig` should be:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "include": [
    "./server/**/*.ts",
    "./shared/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

In your example, I don't think you need two `tsconfig` files.